# Portable Library Error on deserialization array of objects

Tags: serialization, xamarin.ios, json.net

I have a WebApi returning the following JSON which I am trying to deserialize to the object below

**JSON OBJECT**

```
{
    "results": [{
            "id": 123456,
            "fullName": "Foo Bar",
            "localName": null,
            "jobPosition": "ME",
            "jobCompanyName": "EXTRA",
            "jobLocationCountry": "United States of America",
            "jobLocationCity": "San Francisco",
            "jobCountrySubdivision": "California",
            "boards": [],
            "restrictionsIndicator": false,
            "personRestriction": null,
            "jobRestriction": null
        }, {
            "id": 789101,
            "fullName": "Foo Bar",
            "localName": null,
            "jobPosition": null,
            "jobCompanyName": "Unknown",
            "jobLocationCountry": "Unknown",
            "jobLocationCity": "Unknown",
            "jobCountrySubdivision": "Unknown",
            "boards": [{
                    "companyId": 667525,
                    "companyName": "FOO BAR COMPANY",
                    "companyOffLimits": null,
                    "restrictionCategoryId": null
                }
            ],
            "restrictionsIndicator": false,
            "personRestriction": null,
            "jobRestriction": null
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": 2,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 100
}
```

**C# Classes**

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }
    public int pageNumber { get; set; }
    public int resultsPerPage { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public object localName { get; set; }
    public string jobPosition { get; set; }
    public string jobCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string jobLocationCountry { get; set; }
    public string jobLocationCity { get; set; }
    public string jobCountrySubdivision { get; set; }
    public Board[] boards { get; set; }
    public bool restrictionsIndicator { get; set; }
    public int? personRestriction { get; set; }
    public int? jobRestriction { get; set; }
}

public class Board
{
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public int? companyOffLimits { get; set; }
    public object restrictionCategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

The DLL is a Portable Class Library which is .NET 4.5 and i have JSON.net(10.0.1) installed via nuget, but the portable library is connected to a xamarin IOS Project on a mac.

If the JSON being deserialized has no `Boards` it works out fine but if there is a `Board` then I receive the following message.

```
Unable to find a constructor to use for type Board. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path 'results[1].boards[0].companyId'
```

The Settings I am using are:

```
var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings
{
    NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),

};
```

I have tried the following ways to get it to serialize:

1. `var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(_jsonString, settings);`
2. `var jobject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(_jsonString, new Rootobject());`

i have tried the following

- Put in a default constructor
- Naming all the parameters for the class in a constructor
- Adding the Attribute to the constructor
- Changing the Boards to a List
- Taking out the Boards Property

but there is still no joy. It will not deserialize for me.

Comment: "I receive the following message" - you didn't post the text of the error message.  You also use the term "serialize" a few times when I think you mean "deserialize" - this is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, trying to do a million things at once. Question has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to modify this

```
public class Board
{
    public int companyId { get; set; }
    public string companyName { get; set; }
    public int? companyOffLimits { get; set; }
    public object restrictionCategoryId { get; set; }

    **public Board(){}**
}
```

also in other classes

or also change

```
public Board[] boards { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Board> boards { get; set; }
```

Try....

Comment: Tried that too `Changing the Boards to a List`

Comment: can you post the JSON?